# How to make user to logged into website & redirect to homepage after successful registration?

Tags: user-registration

Whenever user singup through the registration form, they should automatically logged into website and redirected to homepage.

Is it possible without any plugin?

Comment: quite common and easy thing to do, if you would have searched : https://wordpress.org/support/topic/auto-login-after-register-and-redirect-to-profile-page, You can specify any URL in redirect option

Comment: @svan, I tried the same url. Its working but email is not send to registered user!! I need use to get email too!!

Comment: Post your code please.